# Will I be allowed to go to Mexico without a visa if I hold a British and a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, india, mexico

I am currently living in the UK on a Tier 2 visa and have a multiple entry Schengen visa valid until 2022. Do I need a Mexican visa? The Mexican embassy in India told me I do not. However, VisaHQ in the UK told me I do. Will I need to apply for a visa? And if I don't, will I be allowed to board the flight?

Answer (score 10):

**You Do Not** need a Mexican visa

> With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico, effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired) Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union).

Source: https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico

Another, unambiguous version of the same statement:

> Please note that travellers who wish to visit Mexico (regardless of their nationality or itinerary), holding a valid, multiple entry visa for the United States of America, Canada, Japan, the United Kingdom or the Schengen Space countries DO NOT need to apply for a tourist, business or transit Mexican visa.

Source: https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/sudafrica/index.php/english/visa-for-mexico

Comment: (+1) Unfortunately, the info from this consulate is somewhat confusing. Does “United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union)” means Schengen area and UK? European Union? Both? Does it include Ireland? Iceland, Switzerland, and Norway? Cyprus, Bulgaria, Romania, and Croatia?

Comment: @Relaxed Schengen or the UK, as shown in Timatic

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a visa.

From Timatic:

> Visa Exemptions: Passengers with a valid visa issued by Canada, Japan,
>   USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of
>   180 days.

Since Timatic is the database relied on by the airlines you'll have no trouble boarding.